# pass generic class with multiple constraint as parameter

Tags: vb.net, generics

i am working on one vb.net migration project ..project has some core dll..core dlls are updated based on the update need to re-write wrapper class

Existing dll code:

```
 public abstract class BusinessService : IPayload, IPayload2, IParserContext
```

existing code

```
 Public Sub Execute(ByVal pBs As BusinessService, ByVal pExecuteMode As ExecuteModes)
        If pExecuteMode = ExecuteModes.AwaitAsynchronous Then
            Me.Execute(pBs, Me.AWAIT_TIME_IN_MILLISEC)
        Else
            mStartTime = Now()
            mBsExecuterHelper = New BsExecuterHelper
            mBsExecuterHelper.Execute(pBs, pExecuteMode)
        End If
    End Sub
```

New Dll code:

```
public class BusinessService<TRequest, TResponse> : 
    IBusinessService where TRequest : BsRequest, new() where TResponse : BsResponse, new()
  {

  }
```

now i need to pass BusinessService as parameter to Existing code .i am struck here can anyone help me how to pass generic class as parameter with multiple constraint

Comment: What are the methods from `BusinessService`  that you use inside your `Execute` (and the methods called inside `Execute` like `Me.Execute` and `mBsExecuterHelper.Execute`)? Are these methods also defined inside the `IBusinessService` interface from the new code? Can you provide details?

Comment: below Are new IBusinessService
public interface IBusinessService
  {
    string EbcName { get; set; }

    string ServiceName { get; set; }

    event EventHandler<ServiceExecutedEventArgs> ServiceExecuted;

    string MarshallRequest();

    void UnmarshallResponse(string xml);

    string GetResponseXml();

    string GetRequestXml();

    void RaiseServiceExecuted(object sender, ServiceExecutedEventArgs e);
  }

Comment: Yes. But does it contain the methods that you need inside `Me.Execute` and `mBsExecuterHelper.Execute`?

Comment: Do you want your `Execute` method to be generic? i.e., do you want it to take a parameter of type `BusinessService<TRequest, TResponse>` for any `TRequest` or `TResponse`? Or for specific `TRequest` and`TResponse`?

Comment: yes ..Execute  to be generic and this Execute Method should take 2 parameters..
Public Sub Execute(ByVal pBs As BusinessService)
        Me.Execute(pBs, ExecuteModes.Synchronous)
    End Sub
here i need to pass 2 parameter in the place of BusinessService ...

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Class BsExecuter
    Private WithEvents mAwaitTimer As System.Windows.Forms.Timer
    Private Const AWAIT_TIME_IN_MILLISEC As Integer = 50
    Private WithEvents mBsExecuterHelper As BsExecuterHelper
    Public Delegate Sub CallBackMethod(ByVal pBusinessService As BusinessService, ByVal pException As Exception)
    Public Event BsExecuted(ByVal pBsExecuter As BsExecuter, ByVal pBusinessService As BusinessService, ByVal pException As System.Exception)
    Private mStartTime, mEndTime As Date
    Private mLogger As ILog
    Enum ExecuteModes
        Synchronous = 1
        Asynchronous = 2
        AwaitAsynchronous = 3
    End Enum
    Enum ExecuteStates
        NotStarted = 1
        Running = 2
        Finnished = 3
        Cancelled = 4
    End Enum
    Public Sub Execute(ByVal pBs As BusinessService)
        Me.Execute(pBs, ExecuteModes.Synchronous)
    End Sub
    Public Sub Execute(ByVal pBs As BusinessService, ByVal pExecuteMode As ExecuteModes)
        If pExecuteMode = ExecuteModes.AwaitAsynchronous Then
            Me.Execute(pBs, Me.AWAIT_TIME_IN_MILLISEC)
        Else
            mStartTime = Now()
            mBsExecuterHelper = New BsExecuterHelper
            mBsExecuterHelper.Execute(pBs, pExecuteMode)
        End If
    End Sub
    Public Sub Execute(ByVal pBs As BusinessService, ByVal pAwaitTimeInMillisec As Integer)
        mBusinessService = pBs
        mAwaitTimer = New System.Windows.Forms.Timer
        mAwaitTimer.Enabled = True
        mAwaitTimer.Interval = pAwaitTimeInMillisec
        Debug.WriteLine("Called: " & Now().ToString("ss.ffff"))
        mAwaitTimer.Start()
    End Sub
    Private Sub mAwaitTimer_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles mAwaitTimer.Tick
        mAwaitTimer = Nothing
        Debug.WriteLine("Starts: " & Now().ToString("ss.ffff"))
        mStartTime = Now()
        mBsExecuterHelper = New BsExecuterHelper
        mBsExecuterHelper.Execute(mBusinessService, ExecuteModes.Asynchronous)
        mBusinessService = Nothing
    End Sub
    Public Sub Execute(ByVal pBs As BusinessService, ByVal pAddressOfCallbackMethod As CallBackMethod)
        Me.Execute(pBs, pAddressOfCallbackMethod, ExecuteModes.Synchronous)
    End Sub
    Public Sub Execute(ByVal pBs As BusinessService, ByVal pAddressOfCallbackMethod As CallBackMethod, ByVal pExecuteMode As ExecuteModes)
        mStartTime = Now()
        mBsExecuterHelper = New BsExecuterHelper
        mBsExecuterHelper.Execute(pBs, pAddressOfCallbackMethod, pExecuteMode)
    End Sub
    Public Sub Cancel()
        mBsExecuterHelper.ExecuteState = ExecuteStates.Cancelled
    End Sub
    Private Sub mBsExecuterHelper_BsExecuted(ByVal pBusinessService As BusinessService, ByVal pException As System.Exception) Handles mBsExecuterHelper.BsExecuted
        mEndTime = Now()
        Me.LogBusinessService(pBusinessService)
        RaiseEvent BsExecuted(Me, pBusinessService, pException)
    End Sub
    Private Sub mBsExecuterHelper_ExecuteCallBack(ByVal pBusinessService As BusinessService, ByVal pException As System.Exception) Handles mBsExecuterHelper.ExecuteCallBack
        mEndTime = Now()
        Me.LogBusinessService(pBusinessService)
    End Sub
    Private Sub LogBusinessService(ByVal pBusinessService As BusinessService)
        If Not (pBusinessService Is Nothing) Then
            Dim vLoggString As String = ""
            Dim vExecTime As TimeSpan
            Dim vExecTimeInSek As Double
            mLogger = LogManager.GetLogger(pBusinessService.GetServiceName())

            vExecTime = mEndTime.Subtract(mStartTime)
            vExecTimeInSek = vExecTime.Milliseconds / 1000
            'vLoggString = "Start:" & mStartTime.ToString("HH:mm:ss,ffff") & " End:" & mEndTime.ToString("HH:mm:ss,ffff")
            vLoggString = "ExecutionTime:" & vExecTimeInSek.ToString("#####0.0") & "s"
            vLoggString &= " User:" & Environment.UserName
            vLoggString &= " Request:" & pBusinessService.GetRequestXml()
            mLogger.Info(vLoggString)
        End If
    End Sub
#Region " BsExecuterHelper "
    Private Class BsExecuterHelper
#Region "Used by main thread"
        Private mThread As Thread
        Private mExecuteModes As ExecuteModes
        Private mCallBackMethod As CallBackMethod
        Shared Sub New()
            SharedTimer = New System.Windows.Forms.Timer
            SharedTimer.Enabled = True
            SharedTimer.Interval = 70
        End Sub
        Public Event BsExecuted(ByVal pBusinessService As BusinessService, ByVal pException As System.Exception)
        Public Event ExecuteCallBack(ByVal pBusinessService As BusinessService, ByVal pException As System.Exception)
        Private Sub mPrivateTimerReference_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles mPrivateTimerReference.Tick
            mPrivateTimerReference = Nothing
            If Not mCallBackMethod Is Nothing Then
                RaiseEvent ExecuteCallBack(mBs, mException)
                mCallBackMethod(mBs, mException)
            Else
                RaiseEvent BsExecuted(mBs, mException)
            End If
        End Sub
        Public Sub Execute(ByVal pBs As BusinessService, ByVal pExecuteMode As ExecuteModes)
            mBs = pBs
            mExecuteModes = pExecuteMode
            ExecuteState = ExecuteStates.Running
            If pExecuteMode = ExecuteModes.Synchronous Then
                RunBs()
            Else
                mThread = New Thread(AddressOf RunBs)
                mThread.Name = "BsExecuter"
                mThread.IsBackground = True
                mThread.Start()
            End If
        End Sub
        Public Sub Execute(ByVal pBs As BusinessService, ByVal pAddressOfCallbackMethod As CallBackMethod, ByVal pExecuteMode As ExecuteModes)
            mCallBackMethod = pAddressOfCallbackMethod
            Me.Execute(pBs, pExecuteMode)
        End Sub
        Public Sub Cancel()
            ExecuteState = ExecuteStates.Cancelled
        End Sub
#End Region
#Region "Used by new sub thread"
        Private Sub ServiceExecuted()
            If mExecuteModes = ExecuteModes.Synchronous Then
                If Not mCallBackMethod Is Nothing Then
                    RaiseEvent ExecuteCallBack(mBs, mException)
                    mCallBackMethod(mBs, mException)
                Else
                    RaiseEvent BsExecuted(mBs, mException)
                End If
            Else
                mPrivateTimerReference = SharedTimer
            End If
        End Sub
        Private Sub RunBs()
            Dim vException As Exception = Nothing
            Try
                'Use INAF EbcHandler to mock BS calls and for error handling translation
                IKEA.Framework.DomainModel.Context.ServiceContext.EbcHandler.ExecuteBusinessService(mBs)
                'mBs.Execute()
            Catch e As Exception
                vException = e
            Finally
                If Not ExecuteState = ExecuteStates.Cancelled Then
                    ExecuteState = ExecuteStates.Finnished
                    mException = vException
                    ServiceExecuted()
                End If
            End Try
        End Sub
#End Region
#Region "Shared between the threads"
        Private Shared SharedTimer As System.Windows.Forms.Timer
        Private mBs As BusinessService
        Private mException As System.Exception = Nothing
        Private WithEvents mPrivateTimerReference As System.Windows.Forms.Timer
        Public Event ExecuteStateChanged()
        Private mExecuteState As ExecuteStates = ExecuteStates.NotStarted
        Public Property ExecuteState() As ExecuteStates
            Get
                Return mExecuteState
            End Get
            Set(ByVal Value As ExecuteStates)
                mExecuteState = Value
                RaiseEvent ExecuteStateChanged()
            End Set
        End Property
#End Region
    End Class
#End Region
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to make your `Execute` method generic, and be able to take in a generic `BusinessService` as input, the method signature should be like this:

```
Public Sub Execute(Of TRequest As {New, BsRequest}, TResponse As {New, BsResponse})(
                    ByVal pBs As BusinessService(Of TRequest, TResponse),
                    ByVal pExecuteMode As ExecuteModes)

End Sub
```

This of course, will require similar changes to other methods in your class.

You might also decide to make your the whole class generic like this:

```
Public Class BsExecuter(Of TRequest As {New, BsRequest}, TResponse As {New, BsResponse})

    Public Sub Execute(
                    ByVal pBs As BusinessService(Of TRequest, TResponse),
                    ByVal pExecuteMode As ExecuteModes)

    End Sub
End Class
```

Note that in this case, the method is already generic and you don't need to specify the generic constraint on the method because they are already set for the class.

If you don't need your method to be generic, for example, you might want your method to deal with a specific `BusinessService` (e.g.  `BusinessService(Of MyRequest, MyResponse)`), you can do this:

Assuming that these are your special `BsRequest` and `BsResponse` classes:

```
Public Class MyRequest
    Inherits BsRequest

End Class

Public Class MyResponse
    Inherits BsResponse

End Class
```

Then you don't have to make anything generic, and simply you can accept the specific type that you want like this:

```
Public Sub Execute(
                    ByVal pBs As BusinessService(Of MyRequest, MyResponse),
                    ByVal pExecuteMode As ExecuteModes)

End Sub
```